# Make Opera stop displaying each tab on the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, opera

I just switched from Chrome to the newest version of Opera, which I really like, except that in Windows 7, it does the same thing as IE does and acts like every tab is a separate window. I find this to be profoundly annoying, does anyone know if there's a way to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

opera:config#UserPrefs|UseWindows7TaskbarThumbnails

Comment: Thank you! opera:config is neat, I hadn't found that yet. Something tells me I'll be playing with it a lot.